# Watir,click on a date from a date picker 62 days from current date

Tags: date, watir, future

I need to click on a date that is 62 days later than the current date.
The next button for the months is clickable so I have been able to move the calendar to 2 months later but unable to select the date.
Eg if the current date is 4 July then I need to select 6th Sept.

My code at the moment looks somewhat like this.

```
b.element(:name, "policyperiod_endDate").click       <-- datetime picker's click
b.element(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[50]").click   <-- next month
b.element(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[50]").click
b.element(:link,"06").click                                 <--doesnt select 08
b.element(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[68]").click   <-selects fixed cell n
```

how to select 06?

The outer HTML is like this:

```
input type="text" class="pull-left pdr35 ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-       invalid ng-invalid-required" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" is-open="datePickerOpts.datepickers.policyperiod_startdate[1]" ng-model="policyIVOs.policyEndDate" name="**policyperiod_endDate**" datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" close-on-date-selection="true" show-weeks="false" ng-click="open($event, 'policyperiod_startdate', 1)" min-date="policyEndMin" max-date="policyEndMax" required="" readonly=""
```

Comment: The answer depends on the date picker control. Without knowing which one you are using, it is quite difficult to help you.

Comment: Also, be careful with your math/logic because 62 days from July 4th is not September 6th but is actually September 4th.

Comment: Justin: I might sound like a noob..but how may I be able to dig that info...would a css help?

Comment: PJD: I did consider it..its like based on the no. of days a certain fees is calculated in my project so 60-61,62 days is acceptable...

Comment: You want to at least share the HTML you are working with (ie the element(s) that you are trying to click and possibly those around it). You should also explain what "doesn't select 08" means - is there any an exception or does it just do nothing? By the way `b.element(:link,"06")` seems wrong. `:link` is more of Selenium locator than a Watir locator.